# Weird linear-gradient behavior

Tags: css, linear-gradients

am pretty new to CSS. The site is having weird greeny coloring at the top overlay as shown below:
[image]

Where in firefox, the overlay works fine!
[image]

Feel free to checkout at https://highspeedinternet.my/ thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] here in the question that demonstrates the issue? I'm pretty sure not all of the code on the site is needed to show the problem. See also [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1016716).

Comment: @MrLister thanks for bringing that up. Let me edit it after this! Tq

Comment: With Chrome, Firefox and Safari on Mac works in the same way without difference.

Comment: Ok FML, it appears that it happens to my 'problematic' monitor. It works fine after i switch monitor =.=